# Regex matches unspecified ampersand character in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex, escaping

I'm trying to match a set of characters with a pattern. But ampersand is matching without specifying. Could you please explain why Regex behaves like this?

```
string input = "<font face=\"Verdana\">É-øá-É-</font><font face=\"Arial\"> ;&: ant ;ghj\n</font>";

Regex Matcher = new Regex("</font><font face=\"[\\w\\s-_]+\">[ -,:;\\.\\r\\n\\/\\]\\)]+");

string output = Matcher.Match(input);
```

I need the output as

`"</font><font face=\"Arial\"> ;"` 
since the matchable characters after font start tag doesn't contain & character.

But the actual output I'm getting is

`"</font><font face=\"Myriad\"> ;&: "`

Why this regex matches the & character too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the dash `-`.

```
 [ -,
```

means match all character between the space and the comma.

```
SPACE => 32
COMMA => 44
APERSTAND => 38 (matches)
```

Comment: Aah, that was my carelessness indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to escape the dash '-' Change to this:

```
Regex Matcher = new Regex("</font><font face=\"[\\w\\s-_]+\">[ \\-,:;\\r\\n\\/\\]\\)]+");
```